# Ruby on Rails : relationship with "has_many"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Mr X likes only one post made by Mr Y

How can I create a relationship between Mr X and Mr Y to see the Mr Y's posts? (to see the suggested posts)

user.rb

```
  has_many :posts
  has_many :liked_posts, through: :liked, source: :post
```

post.rb

```
  def liked_by?(user)
    likes.where(user: user).any?
  end
```

likes.rb

```
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  user_id    :integer          not null
#  like_id    :integer          not null
```

Should I use uniq ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain if you mean this, but in case you want to relate `User` with `Post` through `Like` then proceed as:

user.rb

```
has_many :posts
has_many :likes
has_many :liked_posts, through: :likes
```

post.rb

```
has_many :likes

def liked_by?(user)
  self.likes.where(user: user).any?
end
```

likes.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :post
```

You'd have to add the respective database migrations to add the attributes to `likes`

Comment: No... I want to create a NEW relationship between Mr X and Mr Y.
For example to see (on the Mr X "dashboard", the other posts made by Mr Y)

Comment: You could have a `friends` relationship one_to_many, this way in X's dashboard you can access to Y posts if they're friends as: `x.friends.find(user: y).posts`

Comment: since `user has_many posts` the later snippet should work once you set the relationship.

Comment: has_many :posts, -> { where liked_posts.user }, :through => :likes ??

Comment: Yes, conditional associations should work as well `has_many :posts, -> (other_user){ where(user: other_user) }, through: :likes` so you can do `x = User.first; x.posts(y)`

Comment: So you can call that new relationship `related_posts` instead of `posts`, and still add the `has_many :posts`. Both should co-exist

Comment: It's a parameter of the scope (lambda)